# Find the HTTP request for specific apache processes

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd, process

I have several apache processes running on a system, which seem to be stuck in infinite loops.

Is there some way I can inspect the apache process to find what the HTTP request was that they are attempting to respond to?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have their IP address or anything that you can trac them by means of a log file or `lsof` output?

You run the following while you had the user try to connect again:

`while true;do lsof -i :8080;sleep 2; done;`

Once you have that listening, you should see something like:

`httpd   2763 http   12u  IPv6 1064421      0t0  TCP localservername:http-alt->someclientsomewhere.com:56074 (ESTABLISHED)`

Note: Right now on this test box I am running HTTP on port 8080.  2763 is the PID.  If you are having alot of traffic, then you might have to filter out the IP address.